# Are there any 8-speed brifters with internal cabling?

Tags: shifter, equipment

I have a situation where the bike has (OEM) 8-speed Shimano Claris shifters with the cables coming out the side which interferes with the handlebar bag.
(Photo below). SRAM doesn't list any 8-speed brifters at all, and Campy 8speed ergos are only available (second hand? genuine?) from Ebay.
I'm looking specifically for brifters with internal cable routing - bar-end shifters are a fallback option.

[image: Shimano Claris with external cable routing]

Comment: Don't know if any brifters, but they do make [bar end shifters](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/ca/en/shimano-ultegra-6480-8sp-bar-end-shifter-set/rp-prod13649) that are 8 speed and the cabling goes under the bar tape.

Comment: To my knowledge there's no such product currently being sold new (unless one of the smaller manufacturers like microshift have them?). It may happen at some point in the future though, since Shimano has brought internal routing down to the Sora 9-speed level, it's possible that with the next refresh of Claris that they'll move it to internal routing too.

Comment: Your other option actually is to use 10-speed Campy brifters. I've never set it up, but the pull ratio between 10-speed Campy and Shimao 8-speed is supposed to be close enough that it works out. You can google "shimergo".

Comment: I know Sunrace makes a "new" 8 speed brifter, but alas they are also external routing : / you could stick two 90º cable noodles on the side of the shifter :D (joke)

Comment: What's the problem with the external cabling?   For me, it gets in the way of the gopro lens.   On the other hand, it clearly shows the Freds on carbon bikes that they got passed by an older bike.

Comment: I edited my answer about the Microshift 8-speed brifters. They are still external routing only.

Comment: @Criggie: "What's the problem with the external cabling?" It gets in the way of a (large-ish) handlebar bag.

Comment: @NateWengert Thanks for that tip: I found that it is indeed possible to use a noodle to turn the cable direction. Someone has done this (https://thecrazyrandonneur.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/how-to-have-a-large-handlebar-bag-with-sti-shifters/), and might be a possible solution. In any case the motivation for this question was to see if a non-hack solution existed at all. As I mentioned in the question, I could also just use bar end shifters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways to do it.

<strike>One is use [Microshift SB-R482 levers.](http://www.microshift.com.tw/SB-R482.html)</strike> (Sorry, I got this wrong because the image is a little tricky and it comes off a link from their front page that says "inner route cables." These have shift cable routing much like STIs with external routing.)

The other is use 10 speed Ergo levers, or 9 speed Ergo levers with the Hubbub/Shimergo mod, to shift Shimano 8 with a Shimano derailer and cassette, as outlined [here](http://www.cyclinguk.org/cyclists-library/components/transmission-gears/derailleur-gears/shimergo). Or if you happen to find an 8-speed Ergo, you can install a 9-speed or 10-speed ratchet ring into it.

Interference with handlebar bags is a big reason why the Shimergo/Hubbub trick became a thing. You can also do the same trick to make 10-speed Ergo work with 9-speed Shimano.

SRAM started at 10 and never went backwards.

Answer (score 12):

The new Claris, called R2000, has internally routed brake and shifter cables, an improvement on a previous version, that still sported the externally routed shifting cables.
It is still 8 speed group, so in line with the op's wishes.

https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/claris-r2000.html

[image: claris R2000 shifters]
<sub>(source: [bike24.net](https://cdn.bike24.net/i/p/4/2/221324_00_c.jpg))</sub>

dealers manual, page 13, how to install shifter cable:
http://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-RBSL001-03-ENG.pdf

Answer (score 5):

They just recently release a new Claris internal cabling R2000 model.

The advantage of this R2000 edition of Claris is that it is 8 speed and has cable routing under the handlebar tape. Internal routing, if you will. This means that you can use it with your 8 speed bike because the cable pull will match your existing Claris derailleur while the internal cables will not interfere with your handlebar bag. Neat.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Although your pocketbook won't like this solution, the Alfine Di2 wireless brifter from Shimano does have an 8-speed option. It's not as much an *internal [shifter] cable solution* as a *wireless shifter and internal brake cable solution*.</strike>

As commenters have pointed out,  the Alfine is for internal geared hubs. You might be able to bodge a solution with their Dura-Ace wireless brifters but it'll be similarly expensive and may not work.

[image: Di2]

Comment: Can those be set up to work with a road derailer, or do they only work with hub gears?

Comment: Only derailleurs. I don't think it'd be easy to modify for internal gear hubs.

Comment: This to me implies that Alfine Di2 only works with hub gears, not derailer gears- http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/city---comfort/alfine-di21.html

Comment: "Alfine" is a model line of Shimano's IGH.  So they will have different pull to derailleurs.