# Anyone know of 3x7 brifters with internal cabling?

Tags: shifter, brifters

Kind of similar to [this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/45070/are-there-any-8-speed-brifters-with-internal-cabling) (sorry for the repetition).

I have an old (beloved) specialized A1 with [Shimano RSX shifters](http://google.com/#q=shimano+rsx+shifters). They periodically suffer from [this problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MyQGB1gudw) where they stop shifting. I'm getting a bit frustrated with periodically having to disassemble or flush out with solvent. So I'd like to treat myself to some brand new, preferably with internal cabling.

Does anyone know if there are shifters with internal gear cabling for 3x7? I've googled around a bit but didn't find anything.

Comment: There certainly are 3x7 options with external cabling. I very much doubt that internal routed 3x7 was ever produced, but who knows! Might as well get a modern groupset, at least that's what I'd do.

Comment: I had RSX and ended up swapping to some 3x10 105 brifters.  There was a time I had the left/triple as RSX and the right/rear as the newer one, but having one gear cable looked too "texan".  Yes this reqiired a new freehub and cassette and chain.

Comment: If you are so inclined, you can convert to flat bar. 3x7 mtb shifters work fine. You need to find brake levers suitable to side pull calipers. Very cheap solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a hack, but you can do this with the current Claris ST-2400 3x8 levers using an alternate cable mounting position on many "classic" shaped Shimano rear derailleurs. (Make sure whatever you're buying says 3x8.)

[image: Alternate cable routing]

Sheldon Brown goes into this briefly [here](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/drivetrain-mixing.shtml#alternate). It tends to work fine in this combination (8-speed shifters on 7-speed.)

Note that all shift-housings-under-the-tape STI levers use the Super SLR brake cable pull standard. They pull slightly more cable and so if you hook them up to calipers not intended for them, the mechanical advantage will be skewed such that it feels firmer but is less powerful. It's not generally a dealbreaker and there are a lot of bikes in the world set up like this, but it is noticeable and I've seen the results be mediocre enough that I tend to avoid it when I can.

Answer (score 5):

9-speed Campagnolo shifters pull very close to the same amount of cable per shift as 7-speed Shimano and has cables routed under handlebar tape. They haven't been made in years, though, so you have to find used or NOS.

For front shifting, all Campagnolo front shifters except Xenon were non-indexed during 9-speed era so compatibility is not an issue.